# Add bluetooth integration in home assistant installed in QNAP cotainer

Tags: linux, docker, bluetooth, dbus, home-assistant

I am running connect my bluetooth dongle inserted in QNAP Nas to a docker image of home assistant created using container station

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  home_assistant:
    container_name: home_assistant
    restart: always
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant:latest
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /run/dbus:/run/dbus:ro
    environment:
      - TZ=Australia/Sydney
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
```

I then used the terminal in the container to install dbus and bluez

```
apk add dbus && apk add bluez
```

I am getting the below error when trying to run the integration in HA

> 2023-09-06 21:25:56.892 WARNING (MainThread)
> [homeassistant.config_entries] Config entry '5C:F3:70:A8:BB:3F' for
> bluetooth integration not ready yet: hci0 (XX:F3:70:YY:BB:3F): DBus
> service not found; docker config may be missing `-v /run/dbus:/run/dbus:ro`: {ex}; Retrying in background

I think i am missing a step of installing [dbus-broker](https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker/wiki). I tried apk add dbus-broker which didnt work (telling the package is not available). [My reference](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/bluetooth/).

Comment: This sounds like a question for one of the linux related stackexchange sites like https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/